# Move textfield up when it is not visible

Tags: swift, xcode, authentication

I want to move textfield up when keyword covers the  textfield. Now I am facing a problem with the moving textfield up: it moves up but every time when I click one of the textfields.

How to move the textfield up only when it is covered by keyword?
Also, I have scrolling when the textfield tapped, but it does not work correctly

Here is my code:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()       
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    
    
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
}



@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            if view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
            }
        }
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }
    var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    keyboardFrame = self.view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)

    var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = self.scrollView.contentInset
    contentInset.bottom = keyboardFrame.size.height + 20
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    let contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
    
    if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
        }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Go with IQKeyboardManagerSwift Library. It will save you days of time.

Comment: @Kudos thank I will look up for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use this cocoapods to manage all text fields

> pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'

1. Install pods in your project
2. Add the below line in your AppDelegate file under the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

> IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true

Here is a reference link -- [IQKeyboardManagerSwift](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager)

Answer (score 0):

Solutions.

First way you can listen `keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification`

Second way you can hide keywords `textField.autocorrectionType = .no`